# Adding percentage to a value using a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sum, helper, percentage

I have the following existing helper in my Invoice model of my Rails application:

```
def total_price
  line_items.to_a.sum(&:full_price)
end
```

What I would like to do is have an additional helper called `total_vat` which adds 20% to the total_price helper. Is this possible?

I will eventually be adding a third helper which calculates the difference so I can print just the amount of VAT due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating multiple helpers is absolutely possible.

```
def vat
  total_price * 0.2
end

def total_price_including_vat
  total_price + vat
end
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks!